# How to define different types of nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I have defined an overall style for the nodes, but I also need a different one as can be seen from the example. It would be neat to have two declarations one for each node, the blue solid and the dotted purple one. I am sure that it is possible but I haven't been able to find out how.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm,
    every node/.style={fill=white, font=\sffamily}, align=center]

\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
 4      &   & 8     &   & 6     &   & 0     & (-)  \\
        & 3  &      & -1 &      &   &       & 4\\
 5      &   & 6     &   & 3     &   & 0     &  (-)  \\
        & 4 &       &   &       &  &    &   1  \\
};

\draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-8.south east);



% Lineas horizontales
\foreach \i in {2,4} {
  \draw (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-\i-8.south east);
}

% Lineas verticales
\foreach \j in {2,4,6,8} {
  \draw (m-1-\j.north east) -- (m-4-\j.south east);
}

\node[draw=blue,circle,fit=(m-1-5)(m-2-6),inner sep = -19pt] {3};

\node[draw=blue,circle,fit=(m-3-3)(m-4-4),inner sep = -19pt] {5};
\node[draw=blue,circle,fit=(m-3-5)(m-4-6),inner sep = -19pt] {7};



  \path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] (0,0)++(-1.8,0.9) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt] (6) {+}
    -- ++(0,-1) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt] (5) {-}
    -- ++(2, 0) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt] (4) {+}
    -- ++(0,1) node[circle,draw=purple!80, inner sep=1pt] (3) {-}
    -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Sample picture

[image]

Comment: Don't define the style of a node in `every node`, unless you really want it for all nodes.  Rather define different styles, for example in a `\tikzset` command (see section 68.5 in the tikz-pgf manual for an explicit example.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel N suggested, you can define your styles with `\tikzset`.

It is not clear to me if you want math nodes or  sans serif text nodes.

Note that a TikZ matrix is itself a node, so to draw the borders just add `draw` in its option (`\draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-8.south east);` is useless, then).

Also pay attention to the for loops, because in your MWE you drew the right and bottom lines twice.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% No more needed in recent TeX distributions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit}
\tikzset{
    bluenode/.style={
        draw=blue,circle
        },
    rednode/.style={
        circle,draw=purple!80, 
        inner sep=1pt,
        fill=white,
        },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(m) [draw, inner sep = 0pt,
    matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex, minimum size=1cm, inner sep=0pt}
    ]
{
 4      &   & 8     &   & 6     &   & 0     & (-)  \\
        & 3  &      & -1 &      &  3 &       & 4\\
 5      &   & 6     &   & 3     &   & 0     &  (-)  \\
        & 4 &       &  5 &       &  7 &    &   1  \\
};

\node[bluenode] at (m-2-6) {\phantom{3}};
\node[bluenode] at (m-4-4) {\phantom{5}};
\node[bluenode] at (m-4-6) {\phantom{7}};

% Lineas horizontales
\foreach \i in {2} {
  \draw (m-\i-1.south west) -- (m-\i-8.south east);
}

% Lineas verticales
\foreach \j in {2,4,6} {
  \draw (m-1-\j.north east) -- (m-4-\j.south east);
}

\path[draw,purple, dashed,very thick] (-1.8,0.9) node[rednode] (6) {$+$}
    -- ++(0,-1) node[rednode] (5) {$-$}
    -- ++(2,0) node[rednode] (4) {$+$}
    -- ++(0,1) node[rednode] (3) {$-$}
    -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]